# How to get selected TableCell in JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am looking for a way to get the selected cell of a TableView control. Note that I don't just want the cell value, I want an actual TableCell object. One would expect that the method:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0)
```

does just that, but it returns a TablePosition object, which gives you row and column information, but I don't see a way to get TableCell object from that.

The reason I need this is because I want to respond to a key press, but attaching an event filter to TableCell does not work (probably because it is not editable). So I attach it to TableView, but then I need to get the currently selected cell.

EDIT: For future readers: DO NOT mess with TableCell objects, except in cell factory. Use the TableView the way designers intended, or you will be in lot of trouble. If you need data from multiple sources in single table, it is better to make a new class that aggregates all the data and use that as a TableView source.

Comment: You can get the data that is stored in the cell, but getting the cell object, I have never done this

Comment: JavaFX reuses cells and rows. There will only be enough cells created to cover what is actually visible in the table and maybe a few extra. Like you said in your edit, create a cell with the functionality you need via the cell factory. It should have all the info it needs to determine its state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just posted an answer that uses this code to edit a Cell.  I don't think you can get a reference to the actual table cell as that's internal to the table view.

```
tp = tv.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
tv.edit(tp.getRow(), tp.getTableColumn());
```

Your method also returns a TablePosition so you can use that as well.

Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21988562/2855515

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to edit a cell, I want to get a reference to it. My cells are not editable.

Comment: Why do you need a reference?  I've tried but learned most things you need a reference for can be done in the cellfactory.

Comment: I have a rather complicated scenario in which cells get their value from multiple sources. When user presses a key, a new window is opened so user can enter data, and then I need to put that data in the cell's value using setItem(). I know that calling setItem() manually is not recommended, but I don't see another way.

Comment: Instead of calling setItem() you should be updating the table model data.  You need a reference to the object that the cells are bound to.  That can be done using `tableView.getItems().get(tablePosition.getRow())`  And then you call the set method for what you want to change.

Comment: I know, but like I said, cells get their values from multiple sources, and I can associate only one model entity with TableView. Anyway, I can see that getting a cell reference from TableView is not possible, so I guess I will need to keep the list of cell references myself as CellFactory produces them.

Comment: I was thinking about the multiple sources and realized you would need something like what you suggested.  Another way might be to make a table model and keep the reference to the source in the model.  That would be easiest if each row came from a single source.

Comment: Yes, a single source is preferred, but not always the most appropriate. I think my solution is elegant, I was just missing this little detail. It is all working as expected now. I will accept your answer, as it at least confirms that what I wanted cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably get downvoted because the OP asked about returning the cell itself, rather than what I'll describe, but a Google search led me here for my issue.

I personally ran into issues trying to retrieve data from an individual cell.

java.is.for.desktop offered buggy code related to this matter, that throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but is on the right track. My goal is to offer a better example of that using a lambda.

To access data from a single TableCell:

```
tableView.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition> observable, TablePosition oldPos, TablePosition pos) -> {
    int    row           = pos.getRow();
    int    column        = pos.getColumn();
    String selectedValue = "";

    /* pos.getColumn() can return -1 if the TableView or
     * TableColumn instances are null. The JavaDocs state
     * this clearly. Failing to check will produce an 
     * ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when underlying data is changed.
     */
    if ((pos.getRow() != -1) && (pos.getColumn() != -1))
    {
        selectedValue = tableView.getItems()
                                          .get(row)
                                          .get(column);

        if ((selectedValue != null) && (!selectedValue.isEmpty()))
        {
            // handling if contains data
        }
        else
        {
            // handling if doesn't contain data
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit**:
I meant to say ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, rather than NullPointerException, I updated this answer to reflect that. I also cleaned up spelling and grammar.

Answer (score -1):

You want to respond to key press? Better don't.

Instead, you could register a listener for focusing of table cells, which would work with arrow keys and mouse clicks on table cells *(and even with touch events, oh my, the future is already there)*.

```
table.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition> observable,
            TablePosition oldPos, TablePosition pos) {
        int row = pos.getRow();
        int column = pos.getColumn();
        String selectedValue = "";

        if (table.getItems().size() > row
                && table.getItems().get(row).size() > column) {
            selectedValue = table.getItems().get(row).get(column);
        }

        label.setText(selectedValue);
    }
});
```

In this example, I am using a "classic" `TableView` with `List<String>` as column model. (So, your data type could be different than String.) And, of course, that `label` is just an example from my code.

Comment: that's not an answer to the question: OP wants the _TableCell_ not the value