# TableVew - Edit cell when KeyEvent is thrown

Tags: java, javafx, focus, tableview

I have an event listener on a TableView that listens for keyboard event.

```
 // Add event listener to table
 table.setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
        TablePosition<SimpleStringProperty, String> focusedCell = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        if (focusedCell != null)
        {
            table.getItems().get(focusedCell.getRow()).set(event.getCharacter());
            table.edit(focusedCell.getRow(), focusedCell.getTableColumn());
        }
    });
```

I am having problems with updating the cell with the new data when a user clicks enter or changes focus to another cell. When you click enter or change focus, the cell becomes empty. I'm not sure why. How can I save the data and update the cell with the new data.

```
// Here is the full code.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewEdit extends Application
{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    TableView<SimpleStringProperty> table = new TableView<SimpleStringProperty>();
    table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setEditable(true);

    table.getColumns().add(this.createColumn());

    ObservableList<SimpleStringProperty> rowData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    //table.getItems().addAll(rowData);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        rowData.add(new SimpleStringProperty(String.format("Cell [%d", j)));
    }

    table.setItems(rowData);

    table.setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
        TablePosition<SimpleStringProperty, String> focusedCell = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        if (focusedCell != null)
        {
            table.getItems().get(focusedCell.getRow()).set(event.getCharacter());
            table.edit(focusedCell.getRow(), focusedCell.getTableColumn());
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 880, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private TableColumn<SimpleStringProperty, String> createColumn()
{
    TableColumn<SimpleStringProperty, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Column ");
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue());
    col.setCellFactory(column -> new EditCell());
    return col;
}

private static class EditCell extends TableCell<SimpleStringProperty, String>
{

    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    EditCell()
    {
        this.textProperty().bind(this.itemProperty());
        this.setGraphic(this.textField);
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

        this.textField.setOnAction(evt -> this.commitEdit(this.textField.getText()));
        this.textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (!isNowFocused)
            {
                this.commitEdit(this.textField.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
        super.startEdit();
        this.textField.setText(this.getItem());
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.textField.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
        super.cancelEdit();
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String text)
    {
        super.commitEdit(text);
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22028502/2855515)  I haven't tested yet with the newest javafx but I could never get focus listener to work unless the cell lost the focus to a control out of the TableView.

Comment: I've tried something similar with no look. I'm still trying to figure it out. I can enter edit mode with a KeyEvent. I'm having problem saving with enter. I've got a situation where I can save with first enter but after that I can';t enter edit mode anymore. Very strange behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These get really tricky; I think anything "behavior-related" (i.e. standard controls reacting to user input) is hard to change and generally not well supported in JavaFX. Hopefully this is an area of the API that will be improved...

There seem to be a couple of different issues. I think that what is happening with the Enter key, is that although this generates an `ActionEvent` on the text field, which commits the edit, etc, the `keyTyped` event still propagates back to the table, causing it to re-enter editing mode. A fix for this seems to be to use a `keyPressed` handler on the table instead (though to be honest this doesn't feel very robust).

The code relies on the default `onEditCommit` handler on the table column to actually change the property value. The `onEditCommit` handler is invoked by the default table cell's `commitEdit` method. The problem with calling `commitEdit(...)` on losing focus is that the default `commitEdit` method first checks if the cell is in an editing state, and does nothing if it's not. It appears that when the cell loses focus, it is taken out of the editing state before the `focusProperty` listener is invoked, so the `onEditCommit` handler is never called. (As an aside, this also prevents example 13-11 "Alternative solution of cell editing" (sic) from working correctly in the JDK 8 u25 (the current version).)

The only fix I can see for this second issue is to directly update the property from the `commitEdit(...)` method. This requires the cell have a reference to the property, which breaks the nice separation between the cell and the cell value.

I rewrote the example using the usual `Person` example and incorporated these two fixes. This example works quite well, though as I said some parts feel as though they are not very robust:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableViewEditOnType extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setEditable(true);

        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        table.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            TablePosition<Person, ?> pos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell() ;
            if (pos != null) {
                table.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 880, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<Person, String> createColumn(String title, Function<Person, StringProperty> property) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(column -> new EditCell(property));

        return col ;
    }

    private static class EditCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

        private final TextField textField = new TextField();

        private final Function<Person, StringProperty> property ;

        EditCell(Function<Person, StringProperty> property) {
            this.property = property ;

            textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

            textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            });
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (! isNowFocused) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            textField.setText(getItem());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            textField.requestFocus();          
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String text) {
            super.commitEdit(text);
            Person person = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()) ;
            StringProperty cellProperty = property.apply(person);
            cellProperty.set(text);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this on 8u20, 8u25,  and the current ea releases of 8u40 (b23) and 9 (b49).

Comment: Nice use of function, I got to start following the java-8 tag.

Comment: I actually generified the `EditCell` completely, so it's an `EditCell<S,T>`, taking a `StringConverter<T>` as a parameter (along with the `property`). It's actually pretty neat, but I thought it obfuscated the actual issue at hand.

Comment: Updated (better) version [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357). Has a way around sharing the property with the cell and refines the UX a little.

Comment: Thanks, love all those gists you have btw.