# Editing numbers in javafx TableView cells

Tags: java, uitableview, java-8, javafx-8

I'm making a fairly involved desktop application for a friend as a way of learning Java, and in particular Java 8 and JavaFX. The application will have lots of tables and work like a highly-specific spreadsheet, and is to do with estimating shipping costs. So far I have learned to use Scene Builder, and using css structures, and devised my own classes to represent the data in the tables. 
This is a cut-down version of my Vessel class:

```
    import javafx.beans.property.*; 

public class Vessel
{
    private  StringProperty name;
    private  FloatProperty deadWeight;

    public Vessel(){
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty("ENTER SHIP NAME");
        this.deadWeight = new SimpleFloatProperty(0);
    }

    public Vessel(String name, float deadWeight){
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name){this.name.set(name);}
    public void setDeadWeight(float deadWeight){this.deadWeight.set(deadWeight);}   

    public String getName(){
        if ( !(name.get().equals("")) || (name.get()==null) || (name.get().trim().equals("ENTER SHIP NAME")) )
            return name.get();
      return null;
    }

    public float getDeadWeight(){return  deadWeight.get();} 

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name;}
    public FloatProperty deadWeightProperty() { return deadWeight;}

    public void clear(){
            this.name.set("ENTER SHIP NAME");
            this.deadWeight.set(0);
    }
}
```

I need to directly edit cells in TableView, which are either floats or Strings. I can do this with strings, from information I've gleaned on this site, but can't figure out how to do floats.

Here is the controller file, VesselController.java:

```
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane; 
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures;

 public class VesselController {  

    @FXML  private AnchorPane root;
    @FXML  private TableView<Vessel> vesselTable;
    @FXML  private TableColumn<Vessel, String> vesselTableNameCol;
    @FXML  private TableColumn<Vessel, Number> vesselTableDWTCol;

    // Reference to the main application.
    private MyMain mainApp;

    //The constructor, it is called before the initialize() method.
    public VesselController() {}

    //Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called after the fxml file has been loaded.
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the vessel table with the columns.
      vesselTableNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        vesselTableNameCol.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell());

      vesselTableDWTCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().deadWeightProperty());

        // vesselTableDWTCol.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell()); //not working, as it needs to reurn a SimpleFloatProperty type
        //so tried this, but don't have a clear idea of what I'm doing
        vesselTableDWTCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Vessel, Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Number> call(CellDataFeatures<Vessel, Number> p) {
                return new SimpleFloatProperty(p.getValue().deadWeightProprerty());
                } 
            });

    }

    //Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
    public void setMainApp(MyMain mainApp) {
      this.mainApp = mainApp;
      vesselTable.setItems(mainApp.getVesselData());   // Add observable list data to the table
        vesselTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
       vesselTable.setEditable(true);
    }
}
```

This is the class that displays errors, and I'm not sure why-- do I need to implement a Callback? If so how do I do this?
Some of this code I gleaned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478525/tablevew-edit-cell-when-keyevent-is-thrown), to try to make it work with Numbers.
The EditCell class I downloaded from [James_D's repository](https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357).

And here is the MyMain.java to run it:

```
    import java.io.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

public class MyMain extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;

    //The data as an observable list of Persons.
    private ObservableList<Vessel> vesselData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //Constructor
   public MyMain() {          // Add some sample data
         vesselData.add(new Vessel()); //init empty row
    }

    // Returns the data as an observable list of Vessels (in this case a single row) 
    public ObservableList<Vessel> getVesselData() { return vesselData; }

    // Shows the vessel overview inside the root layout.
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("My Vessel");      
        show();
     }

    //Initializes the root layout. 
    public void show() {
        try {          
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Load root layout from fxml file.
            loader.setLocation(MyMain.class.getResource("MyUI.fxml"));
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

                // Give the controller access to the main app.
                VesselController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setMainApp(this);

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    } 

    // Returns the main stage.
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Application.launch(MyMain.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I need to modify the EditCell class, and I've tried to create my own "NumberConverter" without any luck-- I don't fully understand generification, but I'm pretty sure I need to go down that path due to the overall final complexity of the application. Apologies for such a lengthy post.

If anyone can provide some guidance that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `EditCell` class. Alternatively, you can use  [TextFieldTableCell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) class.
You need to call `setcellfactory(...)` method for  `vesselTableDWTCol` column (you can do same thing with `vesselTableNameCol` column).

Use the following snippet of code:

```
// this line allow you to edit  cells in `vesselTableNameCol` column 
    vesselTableNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
// this line allow you to edit  cells in `vesselTableDWTCol` column
    vesselTableDWTCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's simplified things for me-- I did need to change my private TableColumn<Vessel, Float>

Comment: Thanks again @Win.ubuntu, EDIT:-- to clarify I did need to change my
`private TableColumn<Vessel, Number>` declaration to
`private TableColumn<Vessel, Float>` in the VesselController class. I also had to make my own `FloatStringConverter` that could handle user input strings without throwing an exception (and convert negative numbers to zero), otherwise no problemo!